# ¿Valor por default del boton dropdown boostrap?

Tags: jquery, dropdownlist, bootstrap

Titulo. ¿Como seria posible para que cuando inicie la siguiente lista desplegable comienze con el value  que le indique?, y no con el primer elemento de la lista. Aun no comprendo de todo este control de boostrap.

```js
$(function(){
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html( $(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
   //trigger event
});
  //trigger event
  $('.dropdown-menu li a').first().trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="dropdown btn-group mb-2">
<button type="button" id="event-estado" class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
 Dropdown
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" data-value="1">Confirmado</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" data-value="2">Caducado</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" data-value="3">Cancelado</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lo he usado, pero por lo que veo, toda la magia esta dentro del bloque:

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
        $(this).parents(".dropdown")
            .find('.btn')
            .html(
                $(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>'
            );
        $(this).parents(".dropdown")
            .find('.btn')
            .val(
                $(this).data('value')
            );
    });

    //trigger event
    $('.dropdown-menu li a').first().trigger('click');
});
```

Al hacer un *clic* cambia la opción seleccionada, entonces deberíamos poder usar esto como base para cambiar la opción al inicio. Además, la línea: `$('.dropdown-menu li a').first().trigger('click');` esta seleccionando el primer elemento de la lista al inicio, puedes comentarla y veras que se muestra la opción: `Dropdown`. Primero refactorizo el bloque:

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
        const element = $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn');
        element.html(
            $(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>'
        );
        element.val(
            $(this).data('value')
        );
    });

    //trigger event
    $('.dropdown-menu li a').first().trigger('click');
});
```

Con la línea `const element = $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn');` estas obteniendo el elemento, posteriormente *creo* que se le añade el html a mostrar y su valor. *Los métodos `.html()` y `.val()` parece que han sido sobreescritos, en **jQuery** no aceptan parámentros (https://api.jquery.com/html/ https://api.jquery.com/val/)*.

Cómo ya sabemos que línea que selecciona el elemento, una opción sería añadir IDs a las opciones y usar el de la opción que quieres por defecto en este punto. Así por ejemplo, quiero seleccionar "Caducado":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
                console.log(this); // HACK:
                const element = $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn');
                element.html(
                    $(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>'
                );
                element.val(
                    $(this).data('value')
                );
            });

            //trigger event
            //$('.dropdown-menu li a').first().trigger('click');
            $('#expired').trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown btn-group mb-2">
        <button type="button" id="event-estado" class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" data-value="1">Confirmado</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="expired" href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" data-value="2">Caducado</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" data-value="3">Cancelado</a>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***NOTA:*** he dejado un `console.log()`, este lo puse para saber el elemento concreto al que debía añadir la ID.